# Canvas pixel coordinate offset after scroll bar is used

Tags: javascript, canvas, coordinates, pixel

I'm using a canvas at the top of a page. Im writing out the pixel coordinates from the canvas at a mousemove event. Normally, the most bottom Y-value is equal to the canvas height, i e. 700px. But after scrollbar is used to scroll down a bit on the page, the bottom y-coordinate in the canvas will change accordingly to say 400px instead.

```
            document.getElementById("mapcanvas").addEventListener("mousemove", getPosition, false);

            function getPosition(event)
            {
              var x = event.x;
              var y = event.y;

              var canvas = document.getElementById("mapcanvas");

              x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
              y -= canvas.offsetTop;



             document.getElementById("canvascoords").innerHTML = "Canvascoords: "+ "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;





            }
```

... Where "mapcanvas" is my div holding the canvas.

Any ideas of making the y-coordinate independent from usage of scroll bar so that the lower y-coordinate always i 700px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, `canvas.offsetLeft` & `canvas.offsetTop` do not account for scrolling.

To account for scrolling, you can use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect`

```
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

var x=event.clientX-BB.left;
var y=event.clientY-BB.top;
```

BTW, you might want to fetch a reference to the canvas element just once outside your getPosition() function instead of fetching it repeatedly inside getPosition().

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mapcanvas");

function getPosition(event){

...
```

Comment: Worked for iPhone but not some Android phones. Very weird.